# Android - Secure place to store sensitive files inside the same project

Tags: android, security, storage, assets, sensitive-data

Let's say I have an Android Project set up and a git repository for it. Where can I put my keystore (and other sensitive files) inside my project so I can be guaranteed that **it will not end up inside the .apk** when I export the app (but will be inside the git repository)?

For instance, I can't put sensitive files inside the `assets` folder because that will end up inside the .apk.

Is there a place to store these kind of files in the Android file hierarchy I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a place to store these kind of files in the Android file hierarchy I am missing?

Put them in the project root. The only file from the project root that is incorporated directly into the APK is `AndroidManifest.xml`, and even that is moving with the new build system and project directory structure.

Or, create some other directory that does not collide with any existing directories and will not be used by Android, like `_stuff/`.

Or, have your project itself be in a subdirectory, putting other related files in a peer directory.

Also, make sure you set up your `.gitignore` properly such that files only go into the Git repo that you actually want in the Git repo.

Comment: "and even that is moving with the new build system and project directory structure", could you please elaborate that a little more?

Comment: @Tiago: Google is working on the Gradle for Android plugin, as a new build system for compiling and packaging APK files. This is being used today directly by a number of developers, plus it is the standard build system for Android Studio projects. The directory structure of a project designed for use with Gradle for Android looks a little different than does the classic structure we have been using since late 2007.

Answer (score 3):

Don't put your keystore anywhere in your source control or project folder even if you have .gitignored it.  It is a personal document, to be treated as you would your SSH keys.

It is better to keep it in an external location, such as your documents folder or personal keystore folder, which you manage yourself.  As you have mentioned, these don't need to end up in the APK so they are purely supporting documents and files.